# Rails Creating a form where entries are saved to different rows in a table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a survey form in rails. The form consists of a number of questions, created by an administrator, and an "answer" text field.
I have the Survey, Question and Answer models setup, however, I can't get the form to display as desired.

```
Survery.rb:
    has_many :questions

Question.rb
    #question_text:string
    #enabled:boolean
    belongs_to :survey

Answer.rb
    #answer_content:string
    belongs_to :question
```

Right now, I have it so that there is a separate "Save" button for each question/answer, however, I would like to do it so that one "Submit" button would save all the entered answers to their respective rows in the DB. This is the part I am having some issues with. I thought about using accepts_nested_attributes_for, however looking through the docs/examples, I don't think it works in this case.

Does anyone have some ideas of how to handle this?
Regards,

Comment: It **does** work in this case. And I recommend that you check out these railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: i wouldnt use double-nested attributes for this (survey -> question -> answer), but create a new model `AnswerSet has_many :answers` or sth similar, then use the `new` form for `AnswerSet` to save your (nested) answers, (maybe along with a name, timestamp, user id etc.)

Comment: @Arjan: I had actually been using that railscast to help me understand the accepts_nested_attributes_for functionality, however, I admittedly missed the second part of that railscast, so I will need to go back and see how to get it working in my use case, and make sure my understanding of it is right

Comment: @MarianTheisen: Whats the advantage of using a separate model, instead of using the nested attributes?

Answer (score 0):

As Arjan mentioned in his first comment to my question, I was able to use the accepts_nested_attributes_for in this case, I just needed to read through the railscast links in more detail:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 (this was more helpful in my case)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

And apply them to my objects correctly. The first time I had tried it, I think my models were not set up correctly. Once I ensured the right relationships between the different models, it worked as expected.